# passing primary key instead of attribute on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an input tag that takes a users input that calls an AJAX dynamically outputs suggestions from my database. The issue is I want to store the primary key associated with that attribute.

I have figured out a way set it to the primary key when the user selects a value; however I would rather only have the attribute displayed on the front end. Essentially what I was thinking about doing was using the option tag and setting the value to the primary key, but after reading the documentation for it, that doesnt look like it would work.

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id = "zip_id" class="tftextinput2" autocomplete = "off" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" onkeyup = "autocompleter()">
    <ul id = "zip_codes_list_id"></ul>
```

JS:

```
function autocompleter() 
{
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#zip_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#zip_codes_list_id').show();
                $('#zip_codes_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#zip_codes_list_id').hide();
    }
}
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) 
{
    // change input value
    $('#zip_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#zip_codes_list_id').hide();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //connect to db here
    $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE zip LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY zip_codes_id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $rs) 
    {
        // put in bold the written text
        $zip = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['zip']);
        // add new option
        // echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['zip']).'\')">'.$zip.'</li>'; (this one only passes the attribute)
        echo '<li " onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['zip_codes_id']).'\')">'.$zip.'</li>'; 
//this one passes the attribute but changes the displayed value to the primary key.
    }
?>
```

As you can see from the PHP file, what I am trying to do is pass in the primary key value but keep the displayed value the attribute. I am not sure how to do that. Should I be using the UL tag?

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't work that way'?

Comment: you cannot set a value to an `<li>` element

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hofivesoye/edit?html,js,output Are you trying to do this?

Comment: What type of inputs do you want to use? text, checkbox, radio, select?

Comment: I think you're confusing lists (ul, ol, li) with selects and options (dropdowns)

Comment: @bassxzero no I created an auto suggest input field using inputs in my database. it has to be a text input

Comment: @DarrenGourley what I wrote above includes an auto suggestion metric. So the user types into an input tag and the database returns values similar to what the user enter. It cannot be a dropdown menu because the user would not be inputting any values in that case.

Comment: Why do you want to shuffle the primary to the client and have them send it back?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you try to the `zip_id` value for the input, but this input contains the `zip` field value - I assume it's the textual representation. There are a few ways how you could save the `zip_id` on the frontend - either store it in the model (if you're using some MVC framework, but I gues it's not the case) or simply add a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="actual_zip_id" name="zip_id">
```

And

```
function set_item(item) 
{
    // change input value
    $('#actual_zip_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#zip_codes_list_id').hide();
}
```

## UPD

Speakng about the entire idea of autocompleting zip codes, it looks pretty nasty, as pointed by [Darren Gourley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3244413/darren-gourley) (check the comments).

So you'd rather validate it with regex first, and then do your db-related logic like that:

```
$('#zip_id').on('change', function(){
  // your stuff
})
```

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, in fact it looks accurate, but this whole concept is a bit crazy. Storing the ID of a zip code instead of the actual zip code? Let's assume we're talking American zip codes, that's over 43000 records in the lookup table which needs to be constantly maintained as zip codes get created and become defunct. An autocompleter doesn't seem right here, aren't zip codes very similar? They're just a sequence of 5 numbers, right?

Comment: @DarrenGourley Yeah, the better appoach would be to validate the input after ``onchange`` is triggered

Comment: Sounds like the better option. I imagine there's some sort of address lookup service for the US that maintains this sort of information.

Comment: I am still a little confused. Are you saying I should create a hidden input field and assign it the primary key? How can make the changes to my PHP code to accomplish that?

Comment: @user3264355 you'll need to change something like  ``$_REQUEST['zip']`` to ``$_REQUEST['zip_id']``. And please, consider @DarrenGourley 's comments and the UPD in my answer.